# Using JQuery to create a convenient data display interface - on demand - thru iframes

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to build a convenient functionality that I plan into rolling into a library function so I can use over an over again.

The common scenario is as follows;

Say we got a regular table with some rows and cols;

Example

```
<table>
    <tr><td>row 1 col 1</td><td>row 1 col 2</td><td>row 1 col 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 2 col 1</td><td>row 2 col 2</td><td>row 2 col 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 3 col 1</td><td>row 3 col 2</td><td>row 3 col 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

and we want the following to happen;

you click on a TD cell ( say row 1/col 1 ) and in response to this click event, a division appears right beneath that row ( with a nice accordion effect ) and that division is basically an iframe streching 100% percent into that division and one whose src includes the value that you clicked on on that cell; something like `site.com?id=THAT_VALUE_HERE`

This way, one can conveniently click on individual cells in this table and the relavant data  is pulled into the iframe on demand, righr beneath whereever it is clicked. And by simply re-clicking on the same value, the iframe division closes. Of course, you may do the same on other cells.

I know this is all possible thru JQuery, but it may take me a while to pull this off without 
  good tutorial.

Could someone point a tutorial as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I understand but wouldn't loading another url's html into that division be very difficult? I think, to keep the complexity down to minimum, I must use iframes. By te way, this is for data view purposes only.

Comment: @jfriend00, no I haven't tried anything. Since I'm new to jquery, this may take a long time unless I set the initial foot right.

Comment: I'd suggest you start working on this and ask questions when you get stuck.  Start with jQuery doc for [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use iFrames for this. You can just do a regular ajax call.

```
$('tr').on('click', function(){
    //You could store target data directly in the td's, or however you want. 
    //This is just a quick example
    var target = $(this).attr('title');

    $.get(target, "", function(data){
        $('#contentDiv').html(data);
    });

});
```